# Glue-pattern to stick two different design patterns

Tags: java, design-patterns, decorator, factory-pattern

I have an entity factory that creates some entities.
I also have a Person entity that creates more specific Persons with the decorator design pattern. 
[image]

On my factory class I have

```
public class EntityFactory {
private final EntityType entityType;

public enum EntityType{
ENTITY1,
ENTITY2,
PERSON1,
CHILD
}; //I want the user to select only one of those 

public EntityFactory(EntityType entityType){
    this.entityType = entityType;
}

public EntityType getEntity(){
    return entityType;
}

public Entity createEntity(){
    switch(entityType){
        case ENTITY1: return new Entity1();
        case PERSON1: return new Person1(new Person()); //problem
        case CHILD: return new Child(new Person()) //problem
        //...
        default: return null;
    }
}
}
```

Both ENTITY1 and ENTITY2 extend Entity and work fine. When I try to create a PERSON1, tells me that PERSON1 cannot be converted to Entity. And that's understood, since `IPerson` doesn't exist inside Entity. My problem is how am I going to make EntityFactory create a specific Person for me? What can possibly be between those two? I am at moment making a reserch on mediator and adapter pattern. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Well, is the Person an Entity? From your diagram they are not. If the Person extends Entity it will work just fine.

note: Do you have a serious reason to use a Decorator here? Isn't inheritance sufficient?

Comment: I've tried it already and the problem remains.It cannot convert Student to Entity.The reason I use Decorator is because firstly I am studying design patterns and I want to learn more about them -of course!- and secondly I want to create those entities dynamicaly at runtime but not all of them.The user must select between Person1 and Child to be created.You see, they have some methods in common and my logic tells me that it is more apropriate _Child ISA Person2, Person1 and Person2 ISA Person and Person ISA Entity_.I tried to make the Person an Entity and didn't take the results I wanted.

Comment: In the line you type "case person 1" you return a Person but your method says "public Entity createEntity()" . You can only return Entity or subclasses of Entity.

Comment: that's exactly the problem I want to solve!I want to make Person and all its subclasses an entity which also implements IPerson. Although I make it an entity, Person1 cannot be converted.

Comment: doesn't person1 extend person?

Comment: Using the way I learned from the Internet, Person1 extends PersonTypeDeterminer, who implements IPerson.

Comment: Do you have a link? It looks confusing. Why would a Person1 extend a PersonTypeDeterminer? From object oriented logic it doesn't make sence.

Comment: here's the [link] (http://www.newthinktank.com/2012/09/decorator-design-pattern-tutorial/)

Comment: The pizza example for a decorator is perfect. I was refering to the logic of Person1 extending PersonTypeDeterminer. All you are tying to do is learn combining patterns right? You could try to have a Pizza factory on top of using decorators. All I am saying is that your design is possibly wrong. The goal of UML is to present your design in a simple manner, but your design is very confusing. Derek Banas(that site's author) has some interesting OOP & OOD videos series. You should understand them more deeply before moving to design patterns.